# Elements in the field extension by adjoining a countable set of indeterminates to base field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

In [this article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82321142.pdf), the author tells that let $F$ be a field with $\mathrm{char}F\neq2$ and $L=F(\ldots,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,\ldots)$ be the field extension by adjoining a countable set of indeterminates $(x_n)_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}$ to $F$.

I would like to ask what the form of its elements is. I think that $L$ is the field generated by $(x_n)_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}$ over $F$. However, recall that the field generated by a set $S$ over a field $F$ is defined as follows.

> Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be an extension field of $F$ and $S$ a subset of $K$. The intersection of all subfields of $K$ containing both $F$ and $S$ is called *the field generated by $S$ over $F$, denoted by $F(S)$*.

However, I am unknown what here $K$ in that article is. Please help me explain this one. Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The elements of $L$ are of the form $f(x_{-m},\ldots,x_m)/g(x_{-m},\ldots,x_m)$ with $f$ and  $g$ polynomials over $F$ in the prescribed unknowns, $m$ an arbitrary natural number, and $g$ chosen carefully to avoid division by zero. Clearly all such objects belong to any field containing $F$ and $S$. Furthermore, such objects form a field $K$ with the obvious operations, and $S\subseteq K$. Conclusion $K=F(S)$.

Comment: Observe that algebra alone does not enable you (nor require) to form infinite products and/or sums, so that's all. Therefore this field looks like the nested union of $F(x_{-m},\ldots,x_m)$ with $m$ ranging over $\Bbb{N}$. Every element of $L$ contains only finitely many indeterminates, but there is no upper bound on the number of indeterminates.